# Centering media object on page using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been looking everywhere on how to center a media-object in Bootstrap in the middle of my page. I think it should be really simple but I can't figure a way to do it. I've put it in a centered column before, but can't center it within the actual column so it looks off. Here's my latest attempt, which still doesn't work. I have `text-align:center` added to center-block CSS. Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

```
    <div id="email" class="center-block">
      <div class="media">
        <a class="media-left" href="#">
          <img src="pictures/computerIcon.jpg" alt="...">
        </a>
        <div class="media-body">
          <h3 class="media-heading">email@example.com</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: A screenshot would really help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear in what container you want to center the media object, I've assumed you want to center it in the entire screen.

- The `html`, `body` and `.outer` container all get a `height: 100%` to make the `.outer` container take up the entire screen.
- The `.outer` container gets a `position: relative` to refer to its position/dimensions when positioning the `.inner` container.
- The `.inner` container gets a `position: absolute` to take it outside of the document flow (otherwise it takes up `100%` of the screens width which is also the reason that the class `.center-block` didn't do anything)
- The top left of the `.inner` container gets moved to the center of the `.outer` container by adding `top: 50%` and `left: 50%`
- To move the `.inner` container back to the center of the screen we need to move it by half its width and height, this is done by the `transform: translate(-50%, -50%).

This solution should work from IE9 onwards (add `-ms-transform` for IE9 support) and only if the content of the `.media` object doesn't get bigger than half the width or half the height of the screen.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.outer {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="email" class="outer">
  <div class="media inner">
    <a class="media-left" href="#">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/64/64" alt="...">
    </a>
    <div class="media-body">
      <h3 class="media-heading">mattkowalczykowski@gmail.com</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked great, thanks! Should have specified that I just meant horizontally centered but that was an easy fix from what you had.

Comment: Hehe :) in that case there might be easier solutions. A great reference on centering is http://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/ btw. I guess that adding `display: inline-block` and `text-align: normal` to the `.inner` and `text-align: center` to the `.outer` would be enough

Comment: upvoted, great answer, thanks for the explanation - I was wondering how/why your code worked!